# i wanna get return the vriable from radio group

Tags: java, android, xml

i wanna use radio group to get two kind for vriable 
this is my radiogroup

```
  public int price(View view) {
        int price = 0;
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.famSize:
                if (checked) ;
                price = price + 10;
                return price ;
            case R.id.singleSize:
                if (checked) ;
                price = price + 20;
                return price ;

        }
        return price;
```

so when i trying to get the code done its give me eror

```
 public String priceMassage(int price) {
        int newPrice = price;
        String priceMassage = "שח" + newPrice ;
        return priceMassage;
    }



    public void Calculate(View view) { 
             //here is when i am getting the eror
        String priceMassage = priceMassage(int price) 
        displayPrice(priceMassage);
    }
```

"שח" mean new shekels 
pls help me

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied/pasted your method definition and left the type arguments in the method call.

Change:

```
String priceMassage = priceMassage(int price);
```

to:

```
String priceMassage = priceMassage(price);
```

And either add a method argument for price here:

```
public void Calculate(View view, int price)
```

or define where to find price.

Comment: what do you mean define where to find price ?

Comment: i keep getting crash eror when i use this
[public void Calculate(View view, int price)]

Comment: First of all, your price method has the same name as your price variable in the method.  Change your method from "price" to "getPrice" or some sort.  Then in your calculate method, try priceMassage(getPrice(view)) in place of priceMassage(int price).  Your code makes it very difficult to understand what you're actually trying to do.